# Can't setup annotation routing in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

Studying Symfony for the time being. Can't even start because of annotation routing isn't working in my project.

I need to route everything in my project asoft/OrganizerBundle with annotation in controllers.

What I did:

E:\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs\symfony.local\organizer\app\config\routing.yml

```
organizer:
resource: "@OrganizerBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
type: annotation

app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
```

E:\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs\symfony.local\organizer\src\asoft\OrganizerBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml:

```
organizer:
resource: "@OrganizerBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation
```

\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs\symfony.local\organizer\src\asoft\OrganizerBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace asoft\OrganizerBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function showMainAction(): Response
    {
        return $this->showDayAction((new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d'));
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/{day}")
     */
    public function showDayAction(string $day): Response
    {
        echo $day;
        return $this->render('OrganizerBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

When I access URL / , I see Error 500 and this in log:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "The controller for URI "/" is not callable. Expected method "indexAction" on class "asoft\OrganizerBundle\Controller\DefaultController". Available methods: "showMainAction", "showDayAction", "setContainer"." at E:\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs\symfony.local\organizer\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver.php line 98 {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): The controller for URI \"/\" is not callable. Expected method \"indexAction\" on class \"asoft\OrganizerBundle\Controller\DefaultController\". Available methods: \"showMainAction\", \"showDayAction\", \"setContainer\". at E:\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs\symfony.local\organizer\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver.php:98)"} []

When I access /2007-05-02, I get error 404 and this:

> request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /2007-05-02"" at E:\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs\symfony.local\organizer\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php line 125 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /2007-05-02\" at E:\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs\symfony.local\organizer\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php:125, Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at E:\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs\symfony.local\organizer\var\cache\prod\appProdProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php:56)"} []

What's wrong? What I need to specify in my yml files??

Comment: `organizer: resource: "@OrganizerBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml" type: annotation` - remove `type: annotation` from this section. It is not annotation type.

Comment: Done + cache cleared. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with:

```
organizer:
resource: '@OrganizerBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'
```

(in gobal routing.yml)

And

```
organizer:
resource: "@OrganizerBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php"
type: annotation
```

- in Bundle's routing.yml

Works only after prod. cache clearing.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing things up regarding the way routes needs to be declared. So if you want your routes to be declared using annotations, first, in the `app/config/routing.yml` you need to get rid of that `resource: "@OrganizerBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"`, and replace it with something like:

```
organizer:
    resource: "@OrganizerBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

(Pay attention to the indentation too)

Second, the way you are calling `showMainAction()` is wrong, because you can not call `format` in that way. Fix it by adding something similar to:

```
/**
 * @return Response
 * @Route("/")
 */
public function showAction() : Response
{
    $datetime = new \DateTime();
    $date = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');

    return $this->testAction($date);
}
```